# Angular Unit Test to check if class exists

Tags: angular

I need help with a unit test -

```ts
it('should check if requestId is present in EAM Request Data', fakeAsync(() => {
  const component = fixture.componentInstance;
   service.method = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(mockData));
   component['methodName'](mockData.id);
     expect(document.getElementById(mockData.id)).toHaveClass('.class-name');
})

private methodName(id: string) {
      let el = document.getElementById(id);
     if(el){
          el.classList.add('class-name');
        } else {
          this.service.method().pipe(
            tap( => {
                  this.notificationService.error(message);
    
            }),
          ).subscribe();
        }

}
```

Here I am adding an Id with value of mockData.id to the dom than adding a class-name on click when I try to run this test I get an error Error: null is not a DOM element

Comment: Please post the original component method that you are trying to cover.

Comment: just added the method in component

Comment: You can use syntax highlighting to make your code more readable as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help :-)

Comment: Why tehre is an `else` without `if`? Why are you testing private methods? Why it is in fakeAsync if there is no async code here? Why are you accessing DOM directly while it is been disouraged?

Comment: Added the if statement, I am testing if a class is added or not to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why the method is private and you are testing it but, if you want to test it, you can do like this:

```
1) Make it public and then test the method alone

let service = Testbed.get(Service);

it('should cover the #methodName() method', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'methodName').and.callThrough();
   
  // If condition
  const id = 'someId';
  component.methodName(id);
  expect(component.methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();
  
  // Else condition
  spyOn(service, 'method').and.returnValue(Whatever the notification.error returns);
  component.methodName(null);
  expect(component.methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();

})
```

This test case should basically cover the if and else conditions of the method, provided you make it public and then test it. Component methods are anywhich ways private to that component only. You can not access that method in any other component or service file. So no use in making it private. Its just my opinion since I am not sure why you made it private in the first place.